# Joint js - animating circle along a path in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, transition, jointjs

I am newbie in Joint js and also with limited javascript skills. What i am trying to acomplish is that when i click on Animate button, the animating circle should follow the path from start to end. It does follow path but not on line.

```
c = V('circle', {
              r: 8,
              fill: 'red'
            });
        var cylinderView = graph.getCell(reserved_path[player[i]]).findView(paper);
        var cylinderPath = cylinderView.vel.findOne('path');
        var cyclic = graph.getCell(jQuery("#"+player[i]).attr('model-id')).findView(paper);
        var cylinderScalable = cyclic.vel.findOne('.scalable');

        var cylinderScalableCTM = cylinderPath.node.getCTM().inverse();

        c.animateAlongPath({
          dur: '5s',
          repeatCount: '1'
        }, cylinderPath.node);

        c.scale(2, 2);

        cylinderScalable.append(c);
```

What i have understood is that cylinderScalable.append(c) line is creating this problem and it could be resolved if i could append the details directly into svg , but i don't know how to accomplish it

Here is my complete code:    https://jsfiddle.net/9espjppv/

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [doc](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.1/vectorizer.html#prototype.animateAlongPath), it might help you

```
  var c = V('circle', { r: 8, fill: 'red' });
c.animateAlongPath({ dur: '4s', repeatCount: 'indefinite' }, paper.findViewByModel(myLink).$('.connection')[0]);
V(paper.svg).append(c);
```